# Android SQLite Exception no such column while inserting

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlexception

I'm having problem inserting values into my table.
I did 2 tables with same principle but the third one is causing troubles :/

Episode class

```
public Episodes (int eID,int seasonID,String episode,String date,String comment, float rating )
  {
    this.episodeID = eID;
    this.seasonID = seasonID;
    this.episode = episode;
    this.date = date;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.rating = rating;
  }


 Episodes e1 = new Episodes(01, 01, "E1", "2012-01-12", "RandomComment01", 5);

 dbManager.addEpisode(e1);
```

My DBDesigner class

```
public class DBDesigner extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SeriesIMDB.db";
public static final String  TABLE_SERIES = "table_series";
public static final String  COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String  COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String  COLUMN_GENRE = "genre";
public static final String  COLUMN_RATING = "rating";
public static final String  COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";

public static final String  TABLE_SEASONS = "table_seasons";
public static final String  COLUMN_SSID = "ssid";
public static final String  COLUMN_SeriesID = "id";
public static final String  COLUMN_SNAME = "sname";

public static final String  TABLE_EPISODES = "table_episodes";
public static final String  COLUMN_EID = "EID";
public static final String  COLUMN_SEASONID = "seasonID";
public static final String  COLUMN_EPISODE = "episode";
public static final String  COLUMN_DATE = "date";
public static final String  COLUMN_EPISODERATING = "rating";
public static final String  COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_SERIES = "create table "
        + TABLE_SERIES + "( " 
        + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key not null, " 
        + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null,"
        + COLUMN_GENRE + " text not null,"
        + COLUMN_RATING + " integer not null,"
        + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_SEASONS = "create table "
        + TABLE_SEASONS + "( " 
        + COLUMN_SSID + " integer primary key not null, " 
        + COLUMN_SeriesID + " integer not null,"
        + COLUMN_SNAME + " text not null,"
        +" FOREIGN KEY("+COLUMN_SeriesID+") REFERENCES TABLE_SERIES("+COLUMN_ID+") ON DELETE CASCADE);";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_EPISODES = "create table "
        + TABLE_EPISODES + "( " 
        + COLUMN_EID + " integer primary key not null,"
        + COLUMN_SEASONID + " integer not null,"
        + COLUMN_EPISODE + " text,"
        + COLUMN_DATE + " text,"
        + COLUMN_COMMENT + " text,"
        + COLUMN_EPISODERATING + " integer,"
        +" FOREIGN KEY("+COLUMN_SEASONID+") REFERENCES TABLE_SEASONS("+COLUMN_SSID+") ON DELETE CASCADE);";



private static final int    DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DBDesigner(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_EPISODES);
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_SERIES);
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_SEASONS);


}
```

My DBManager class  I tried values and rawQuery none of that worked.

```
public void addEpisode(Episodes newEpisode) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    Log.d("addBook", newEpisode.toString()); 
    values.put(DBDesigner.COLUMN_EID, newEpisode.episodeID );
    values.put(DBDesigner.COLUMN_SEASONID, newEpisode.seasonID);
    values.put(DBDesigner.COLUMN_EPISODE, newEpisode.episode);
    values.put(DBDesigner.COLUMN_DATE, newEpisode.date);
    values.put(DBDesigner.COLUMN_COMMENT, newEpisode.comment);
    values.put(DBDesigner.COLUMN_EPISODERATING, newEpisode.rating);


    database.insert(DBDesigner.TABLE_EPISODES, null, values);


    /*database.rawQuery("INSERT INTO "+DBDesigner.TABLE_EPISODES+"("
            +DBDesigner.COLUMN_EID+","
            +DBDesigner.COLUMN_SEASONID+","
            +DBDesigner.COLUMN_EPISODE+","
            +DBDesigner.COLUMN_DATE+","
            +DBDesigner.COLUMN_COMMENT+","
            +DBDesigner.COLUMN_EPISODERATING+")"
                + " VALUES("
            +newEpisode.episodeID+","
            +newEpisode.seasonID+","
            +newEpisode.episode+","
            +newEpisode.date+","
            +newEpisode.comment+","
            +newEpisode.rating+")", null);*/}
```

I hope this is all the data.  Can some one see what am I doing wrong ?
Thank you clever people :)

Comment: Bahaha ... after few other questions I came across this solution       COLUMN_SEASONID = "seasonID";  replace by COLUMN_SEASONID = "_seasonID";   Done the magic.

Answer (score 0):

In your episode `constructor` datatype for rating is defined as float.

```
public Episodes (int eID,int seasonID,String episode,String date,String comment, float rating )
```

But when you are creating database for episode you have defined rating as integer type.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_EPISODES = "create table "
        + TABLE_EPISODES + "( " 
        + COLUMN_EID + " integer primary key not null,"
        + COLUMN_SEASONID + " integer not null,"
        + COLUMN_EPISODE + " text,"
        + COLUMN_DATE + " text,"
        + COLUMN_COMMENT + " text,"
        + COLUMN_EPISODERATING + " integer,"
        +" FOREIGN KEY("+COLUMN_SEASONID+") REFERENCES TABLE_SEASONS("+COLUMN_SSID+") ON DELETE CASCADE);";
```

May be this is causing problems.

Comment: I solve the Exception `_seasonID` with underline character   ,but now I'm storing nothing in Rating (0,0) and  rating number in comment field.